# Problems with CUDA surface reference and CUDA/GL interop (a non-working example)

Tags: c++, opengl, cuda

I've been trying to get a handle on using surface references in CUDA for OpenGL interop. I been able to use a surface object without problems to do exactly this, but I want to support older hardware (compute < 2.5) that does not support surface objects.

Please note: I had a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30321682/cudaerrorinvalidvalue-when-binding-a-surface-reference-to-a-cudaarray-mapped-fro) yesterday, and it was suggested that I write a simple proof-of-problem. In doing that I've run into a slightly different problem, so I'm asking a new question. In this case, in the code listed below, when I call `cudaBindSurfaceToArray` I get the error

```
CUDA error at test.cu:75 code=37(cudaErrorInvalidSurface) "cudaBindSurfaceToArray(outputSurface, textureArray)"
```

Unfortunately this "minimum" sample code is pretty long because of the GL interop. It has no external dependencies, only the CUDA development files, and the CUDA samples. It compiles in Linux with the command

```
nvcc -m64 -ccbin g++ -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -I<samples_path>/NVIDIA_CUDA-7.0_Samples/common/inc -lGL -lglut test.cu -o test
```

This code is very similar to the CUDA example `simpleSurfaceWrite`. I don't understand how the surface reference in my code is any different than the surface reference in that example. For the record, I am able to successfully compile and run `simpleSurfaceWrite`. Please note that this uses [this definition](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__HIGHLEVEL_gbf670802ae6a57b3a7410a8543bfda4c.html#gbf670802ae6a57b3a7410a8543bfda4c) of `cudaBindSurfaceToArray` from the CUDA C++ API, just like `simpleSurfaceWrite`. I am getting a runtime error, not a compile error.

Here's the code:

```
#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda_gl_interop.h>
#include <helper_functions.h>
#include <helper_cuda.h>
#include <helper_cuda_gl.h>

GLuint texID;
GLuint bufID;
GLenum passthroughVertexShaderID;
GLenum simpleFragmentShaderID;
GLenum simpleProgramID;
GLint fragmentShaderTextureID;
cudaGraphicsResource *texResource;
const int width = 640;
const int height = 480;
const int blockSize = 8;

// Define a CUDA surface reference
surface<void, cudaSurfaceType2D> outputSurface;

// Define some simple GL shaders
const GLchar *passthroughVertexSource =
  "#version 130"
  "in vec3 positionAttrib;"
  "in vec2 textureAttrib;"
  "out vec2 texCoord;"
  "void main()"
  "{"
  "  gl_Position = vec4(positionAttrib,1.0f);"
  "  texoord = textureAttrib;"
  "}";

const GLchar *simpleFragmentSource =
  "#version 130"
  "uniform sampler2DRect tex;"
  "in vec2 texCoord;"
  "out vec4 fragColor;"
  "void main()"
  "{"
  "  fragColor = texture2DRect(tex, texCoord);"
  "}";

__global__ void cudaTestKernel() {
  int x = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  int y = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

  float4 sample = make_float4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
  surf2Dwrite(sample, outputSurface, (int)sizeof(float4)*x, y, cudaBoundaryModeClamp);
}

void displayFunc() {
  // Clear the screen (if nothing else is drawn, screen will be blue)
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  // Make the OpenGL texture available to CUDA through the `outputSurface' surface reference
  checkCudaErrors(cudaGraphicsMapResources(1, &texResource, 0));
  cudaArray *textureArray;
  checkCudaErrors(cudaGraphicsSubResourceGetMappedArray(&textureArray, texResource, 0, 0));

  // Bind the array to the surface. This is where I'm getting an error
  checkCudaErrors(cudaBindSurfaceToArray(outputSurface, textureArray));

  // Call the CUDA kernel
  dim3 grid = dim3(blockSize,blockSize,1);
  dim3 block = dim3(width/blockSize, height/blockSize, 1);
  cudaTestKernel<<<grid,block>>>();

  checkCudaErrors(cudaGraphicsUnmapResources(1, &texResource, 0));

  // Call the OpenGL shaders to draw the texture
  // If the CUDA kernel was successful, the screen will be green
  // If not, it will be gray.
  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
  glUseProgram(simpleProgramID);
  glUniform1i(fragmentShaderTextureID, 0);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_NV, texID);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufID);
  glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);

  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
  glUseProgram(0);

  glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  float *floatBuf;

  // Initialize GLUT/GL
  glutInit (&argc, argv);
  glutInitWindowSize(width,height);
  glutCreateWindow("Surface Test");
  glutDisplayFunc(displayFunc);

  // Initialize CUDA
  findCudaGLDevice(argc, (const char**)argv);

  // Create Texture
  floatBuf = new float[width*height*4];
  for(unsigned int i=0;i<width*height*4;i++)
    floatBuf[i]=0.5f;

  glGenTextures(1, &texID);
  glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_NV);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_NV, texID);
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_NV, 0, GL_RGBA32F_ARB, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, floatBuf);

  delete [] floatBuf;

  // Map Texture into CUDA
  checkCudaErrors(cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage(&texResource, texID, GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_NV, cudaGraphicsRegisterFlagsSurfaceLoadStore));

  // Create shader program
  simpleProgramID = glCreateProgram();
  simpleFragmentShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
  passthroughVertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
  glShaderSource(simpleFragmentShaderID, 1, &simpleFragmentSource, NULL);
  glShaderSource(passthroughVertexShaderID, 1, &passthroughVertexSource, NULL);
  glCompileShader(simpleFragmentShaderID);
  glCompileShader(passthroughVertexShaderID);
  glAttachShader(simpleProgramID, simpleFragmentShaderID);
  glAttachShader(simpleProgramID, passthroughVertexShaderID);
  glBindAttribLocation(simpleProgramID, 0, "positionAttrib");
  glBindAttribLocation(simpleProgramID, 1, "textureAttrib");
  glLinkProgram(simpleProgramID);
  fragmentShaderTextureID = glGetUniformLocation(simpleProgramID, "tex");

  // Create Vertex Array Buffer for rendering texture on screen
  #define BUFFER_OFFSET(i) ((char *)NULL + (i))
  float v[] = {-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
                1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
                1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
               -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,

               0.0f, 0.0f,
               width, 0.0f,
               width, height,
               0.0f, height
  };
  glGenBuffers(1, &bufID);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufID);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float)*3*4+sizeof(float)*2*4, v, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
  glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
  glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(sizeof(float)*3*4));

  glClearColor(0.f,0.f,1.f,1.f);
  glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I have that issue as well.

Comment: @Mewa, no, I didn't. For older hardware support I ended up using global memory and copying the data back and forth. This definitely is not ideal since it turns out to be pretty slow, but supporting older hardware isn't high on my priority list either. I'd love to know if you find the answer!